# hazelcast management center: cannot create mapping for iMap<Long, Map<String, Item>>

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

In hazelcast managment center, why I can't create mapping for iMap cache: iMap<Long, Map<String, Item>>?

It throws this error: "Failed to get SQL DDL mapping for map xyz-cache on cluster hz_cluster"

How to pin down the issue? can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try `SHOW MAPPINGS` to see if the mapping is there.

It's likely missing, due to an earlier issue with it's definition.

Something like this would define it

```
CREATE MAPPING "m" 
TYPE IMap
OPTIONS (
'keyFormat'='varchar',
'valueFormat'='java','valueJavaClass'='java.util.HashMap'
)
```